# Poisson probability of observing at least one zero out of k independent cases

Tags: r, probability, poisson-distribution

I have a set of observations from a biological experiment. I have counted the occurrences of a  particular event on each of the chromosome for $n$ cells and finally I have the final mean value for each chromosome.

```
2.2, 6.4, 3.4, 10.2, 4.45
```

So I have 5 chromosomes making on an average of above mentioned number of events.

I have calculated the Poisson probability of any of the above chromosome becoming zero.

I have used R function: `ppois(q=0,lambda=wt[1:5])` and got probabilities `1.108032e-01 1.661557e-03 3.337327e-02 3.717032e-05 1.167857e-02` , which shows there is total probability of 0.15 so to observe any chromosome with zero event.

Now I want to know at what values, these probabilities become zero or negligible. How can I proceed to achieve this?

Comment: Since you're only interested in the discrete outcome of 0 events, `dpois()` (density function) is what you're after --- the probability of exactly 0 events for each of the chromosomes.  So in this case you don't need the cumulative distribution function `ppois()` since ppois and dpois agree for the case of 0 events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on your question.

Here's how I've interpreted it:

*You're got 5 chromosomes, you're interested in the event that **any one of them** is zero independent of the rest of them, and you're calling this the "total probability".  You'd like to know what combination of individual rates ensures that this total probability is zero or negligible.*

The key is what you mean by negligible.

If you are willing to accept a **1%** chance that none of them are zero, then your answer is `lambda=6.3`, with all chromosomes having a uniform rate.

```
 > sum(dpois(x=0,lambda=rep(6.3,5)))    # uniform rate for all 5 chromosomes
 [1] 0.009182           # less than 1% total probability
```

For a **5%** chance, the answer is `lambda=4.7`.

The individual rates, however, could be smaller or larger, provided they contribute to keep the total within tolerance.  For example:

```
 > sum(dpois(x=0,lambda=c(6,6,7,8,8)))  # non-uniform rates
 [1] 0.00654   # also less than 1% total probability
```

---

**Solution (uniform rates):**

Define a function that does the calculation.  Here I've assumed all rates are equal, though you can set lambda directly to `rate` and pass in any vector of rates.

```
 all_chrom_zero <- function(rate) {
     sum(dpois(x=0,lambda=rep(rate,5)))
  }
```

Then use `sapply` to run it over a list of trial rates, and choose the smallest rate that comes in under your confidence threshold -- in this case 1%

```
 tol <- 0.01
 wt<-seq(0,10,0.1)   # candidate rates
 min(wt[which(sapply(wt,all_chrom_zero)<0.01)])
 [1] 6.3
```

---

The above code has been structured to take a matrix without too much difficulty (using `sapply`). So you could do away with the uniform assumption entirely and actually run your code to simulate over various 5-tuples of rates.

This would be a plus if your biological model has information about the distribution of the rates of the individual chromosomes.  If not, you could draw random samples from a Gaussian distribution for each chromosome's rate, each centred at the uniform solution, and run the calculations over these, or if you like brute force calculations, you could (just for fun!) also run the calculation over a 5D grid and look for the "equiprobable" curves at various tolerance levels.

*Background for `sapply`*
Using `sapply` allows one to avoid explicit looping in R and is quite powerful for building simulations.  If you want a bit of background, I've referenced some [useful primers in an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23282110/181638).

Comment: Hi, how did you calculate the lambda of 6.3 ? But, biologically chromsomes would not have uniform rate of event, its in direct relation with the size.

Comment: @poisonAlien: I've expanded the answer to include the code.  Note -- 6.3 is the solution to the 1% tolerance, not 5%.  With 5% tolerance it's actually a rate of 4.7.

Comment: @poisonAlien: The general case is accessible by running a quick simulation.  I've structured the code above to illustrate how you could feed in a candidate list of 5-tuples and run the calculations using `sapply`.  Follow the link for more background.

Comment: No simulation is needed because simple exact solutions are easy to obtain. The Poisson parameter for which $x$ is the chance of observing at least one $0$ out of $k$ independent cases is given by $-\log(1-(1-x)^{1/k})$. In `R`, with $k=5$, this can be calculated and plotted as `curve(-log(1 - (1-x)^(1/5)), 0, .1)`. For instance, your result of $6.3$ (which should be $6.210\ldots$) can be read off this curve at the point $x=0.01$.

Comment: @whuber: Nice! (+1)

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the suggestions. I really appreciate it. Based AssadEbrahim and whuber suggestion I was able to come to a number which was reasonable given our biological sample. Thank you all again. I am going to accept this as an answer, eventhough every suggestion was helpful.

Answer (score 5):

```
## Just repeating what you did for completion
> wt <-  c(2.2,6.4,3.4,10.2,4.45)
> p  <-  ppois(q=0, lambda=wt)
> 
> sum(ppois(q=0,lambda=wt))
[1] 0.1575537
> 
> tol <- .Machine$double.eps # 2.220446e-16
> wt  <- seq(0,250, by=0.01)
> wt[which( ppois(q=0, lambda=wt) < tol )[1]]
[1] 36.05
```

So when the poisson rate is about 36, the probability that the random variable is 0 is minuscule. Of course you can consider different tolerance levels (I used the smallest number that my computer's R could handle, but that is pretty extreme)

This is a pretty ad hoc way of going about it, and you can probably formalize it with a hypothesis test.

Comment: Hm, not sure about your middle expression.  I think the OP did simply `sum(ppois(q=0,lambda=wt))` = 0.1576   This is the meaning that *at least one* of the chromosomes has a 0 event.

Comment: I think a machine epsilon interpretation of negligible is too harsh, leading your answer of a rate of 36 to be much higher than I would say one is interested in in practical terms.  OP needs to confirm.

Comment: @AssadEbrahim Yes I did the sum(ppois(q=0,lambda=wt))

Comment: @Benjamin Hi, to interpret the answer of 36.05 - so now I have a total of 26.65 events across all 5 chromsomes. So according to this , a cell would have to make around 36.05 total events to ensure that every chromsome would have least probability of zero events rite? Is it possible to know the chromsome wise distribution/breakdown of this 36.05?

Comment: The 36 number is applicable to just one random variable with poisson distribution (i.e. one chromosome), To consider all 5 it is a bit more complicated (as the answer by @AssadEbrahim demonstrates).